# RestAssured. Change authorization way on the fly

Tags: java, rest, junit, rest-assured

I'm curious if there is a way to change authorization type on the fly. 
For example, I have method before test execution.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {

    RestAssured.authentication = RestAssured.preemptive().basic(user, password);

}
```

How can I reset this auth, so I can do next request with auth information put in query parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it

```
RestAssured.authentication = RestAssured.DEFAULT_AUTH;
```